# Is this code duplication and how to avoid it when using Mathematical Operators in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
export function addition(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
}

export function subtraction(a: number, b: number) {
    return a - b;
}
```

The code is the same except the operator. Is it possible to avoid code duplication in such cases?

Comment: Yes, if you pass the operator as parameter to function.

Comment: The only duplication I see are the functions themselves - why not just write `4 + 5` instead of `addition(4, 5)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The original code is fine**

If you need to use functions here (for example, because you need to pass them to other functions) then your original code is fine. The duplication you mentioned is just (boilerplate) syntax. There is no shared functionality between the two functions.

**Using operators directly**

If you don't need to use functions, then you can simply use those operators directly. That is, instead of writing:

```
var result = addition(4, 5);
```

you would write:

```
var result = 4 + 5;
```

**Passing functions as arguments**

Alternately, you could write a higher-order function that accepts another function:

```
function applyOperation(a: number, b: number, operation: (x: number, y: number) => number): number
{
    return operation(a, b);
}
```

A bit silly in this case - `applyOperation(4, 5, add)` amounts to the same as `add(4, 5)` - but it can be useful in other situations.

**Too much deduplication?**

You also posted [another question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149744/how-to-avoid-duplicate-if-else-statements-within-a-typescript-switch). There you're showing a single function that can add or subtract numbers, but it can also return a string representation of an add or subtract expression. Those are two different kinds of functionality that each deserve their own function(s). Putting them together into a single function actually decreases code quality: you end up with a function that's harder to understand and easier to use incorrectly.

Having separate functions (`evaluate` and `toString`, for example) makes it more obvious what they're doing and how they should be used. Using enums instead of strings (`enum Operator { Add, Subtract }`) makes it obvious what the available options are. And perhaps it's better to create an `Expression` class (making `evaluate` and `toString` member functions), with different child classes for different operators. It's hard to tell what the best solution is without knowing more about the actual context though.

Answer (score 1):

As @PieterWitvoet said, unless there's a really good reason to use a function, i would use the + - operators directly.

Example:

Instead of using

```
const result = addition(10, 10);
```

Just use the following directly

```
const result = 10 + 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, it's unclear why you can't just use the operators directly rather than requiring a function.  That said, your goal seems somewhat dubious.  Not all duplication is bad, sometimes it's necessary and indeed can reduce duplication elsewhere for a net gain.

[Your own solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/149740/4203), illustrates this by introducing an extra parameter for the operator.  You've gone from having two single line functions to a single, more complex function 6 line function.  You've also increased the overhead from every call.  Rather than calling `addition(5,6)` every call now also has to pass in an extra parameter to indicate the operation to perform.  You've pushed the duplication outside of the function.

It may be that this makes sense, however it seems unlikely with the context given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to pass the operator as a parameter to the function as advised by @Tushar, but that does not seem to work directly. Indirectly it could be done as follows:

```
export function operator(a: number, b: number, c: string) {
    switch (c) {
      case 'add':
        return a + b;
      case 'sub':
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

The abbreviations and some inspirations were found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5089e0/how-to-use-arithmetic-operators-in-typescript/).

Comment: I don't think this is an improvement at all. This function is easy to use incorrectly (by passing it a string that's not `add` or `sub`), its name is less descriptive and it's less performant due to the extra check involved.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet If you know a better solution, please post it.