# How to avoid duplicate if-else statements within a Typescript switch?

Tags: typescript

```
export function operator(a: number, b: number, operator: string, type: string): string | number {
    switch (operator) {
        case 'add':
            if (type == "answer") {
                return a + b;
            } else if (type == "assignment") {
                return a.toString() + " + " + b.toString();
            }
        case 'sub':
            if (type == "answer") {
                return a - b;
            } else if (type == "assignment") {
                return a.toString() + " - " + b.toString();
            }
    }
}
```

How to avoid code duplication in a Typescript switch?

**Attempt**

```
if (operator == 'add' && type == "answer") {
    return a + b;
} else if (operator == 'add' && type == "assignment") {
    return a.toString() + " + " + b.toString();
} else if (operator == 'sub' && type == "answer") {
    return a - b;
} else if (operator == 'sub' && type == "assignment") {
    return a.toString() + " - " + b.toString();
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [conditional/ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
return type === 'assignment' ? a + ' + ' + b : a + b;
```

`toString()` when working with strings, work as string concatenation operator and operands will be implicitly casted to string. Thus, `toString()` in `else` is not required.

Note that, the code is not equivalent to `if...else if...`, this is `if...else` code and is equivalent to

```
if (type === 'assignment') {
    return a + ' + ' + b;
} else {
    return a + b;
}
```